# Getting error while preparing flutter app for release

Tags: flutter, dart

Getting the following error when preparing the flutter app for release in the visual studio code.

Integrity check failed: `java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still facing this issue, Update Android Studio IDE to the latest version `4.2` and regenerate the jks file again then build your `apk` or `appbundle`.
and the issue will not appear again.
Steps to update Android Studio
In the main page of Android Studio go to this path

```
Configure/Preferences/Appearance & Behavior/System Settings/Updates
```

and press **Check Now** for checking any updates